# How can I restrict dates to some number of days from some date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, maxdate, mindate

I would like to ask how to restrict the mindate/maxdate from a selected date.

For example, I have two datepicker, picker_A and picker_B.

I selected 2020/01/29 in picker_A. Then, I need to restrict the date range in picker_B to allow only 10 days before/after "2020/01/29" can be selected in picker_B.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option  to dynamically change the https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate (and or maxDate) on the second datepicker, when the first datepicker changes.

Answer (score 0):

this code use jquery datepicker method for assign datepicker to your controls.

I use minDate and maxDate properties to set date range.

for calculate 10 days before selected date:

```
var minDate = new Date(maxDate - (10 * 86400000));
```

1 Hour = 3600 seconds
24 Hours = 86400 seconds.

but we need miliseconds.
so:
86400 * 1000 = 86400000 ms.
10 * 86400000 = 10 Days

Answer (score -1):

```js
    $(function () {
        $("#From").datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            constrainInput: true,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                var maxDate = new Date(date);
                var minDate = new Date(maxDate - (10 * 86400000));
                $('#To').datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    minDate: minDate,
                    maxDate: maxDate,
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        console.log(date);
                    }
                }).datepicker('setDate', maxDate);
            }
        }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        var maxDate = new Date();
        var minDate = new Date(maxDate - (10 * 86400000));
        $('#To').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            minDate: minDate,
            maxDate: maxDate,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                console.log(date);
            }
        }).datepicker('setDate', maxDate);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <p>
        <input id="From" type="text" />
        <input id="To" type="text" />
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer could use a bit more clarity. Just a small explanation of how your code works.